# Using sequelize, is it possible to have an association with multiple instances of the same object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

### For Example

Suppose that using the models below, there is one task, **t**.

I would like to create a sequence for doing task **t** twice.  In the database, this is represented by two rows in the `taskSequences` with unique ids and different sequence numbers.

However, when I try to use sequelize to retrieve the sequence and its tasks using this query:

```js
models.sequence.findByPk(1, {include: [{model: models.task}]})
```

, the result only contains one of the tasks.

Is this a limitation of sequelize, or am I missing something?

#### Models

Sequence Model

```js
const sequence = sequelize.define('sequence', {
  name: DataTypes.STRING
}, {});
sequence.associate = function(models) {
  sequence.belongsToMany(models.task, {
    through: models.taskSequence,
    foreignKey: "sequence_id",
    otherKey: "task_id"
  }
}
```

Task Model

```js
const task = sequelize.define('task', {
  name: DataTypes.STRING
}, {});
sequence.associate = function(models) {}
```

TaskSequence Model

```js
const taskSequence= sequelize.define('taskSequence', {
  sequenceNumber: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  task_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  sequence_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, {});
sequence.associate = function(models) {
  taskSequence.belongsTo(models.task, {foreignKey: "task_id"});
  taskSequence.belongsTo(models.sequence, {foreignKey: "sequence_id"});
}
```

### Output

#### Expected

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Example Sequence",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Example Task",
      "taskSequence": {
        "sequenceNumber": 1,
        "task_id": 1,
        "sequence_id": 1,
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Example Task",
      "taskSequence": {
        "sequenceNumber": 2,
        "task_id": 1,
        "sequence_id": 1,
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### What I'm getting

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Example Sequence",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Example Task",
      "taskSequence": {
        "sequenceNumber": 2,
        "task_id": 1,
        "sequence_id": 1,
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have two tasks?

Comment: @kkkkkkk I have one task.  The sequence looks like this: First, do task **t**.  Then, do task **t**.  So one task, but it occurs twice in the sequence.

Comment: Tbh, I don't quite understand. Can you post the current returned data and the expected one?

Comment: @kkkkkkk Sure, I have added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a limitation of Sequelize. It filters out duplicates by default. You should be able to workaround it like this:

```
models.sequence.findByPk(1, {
    include: [{
        model: models.taskSequence,
        include: [{
            model: models.task,
        }]
    }]
})
```

The downside is that the returned data structure will be different from what you want initially

Comment: Also, I had to change the `belongsToMany` association in the sequence model to a `hasMany` association from sequence to taskSequence